# What does "trampling of political norms" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean "political style"?

"This isn’t a defense of Donald Trump, his trampling of political norms or his erratic governance style. But if there’s a leader who is going to set off an economic armageddon, it seems more likely to be German Chancellor Angela Merkel than President Trump."

Source: http://www.marketwatch.com/story/the-world-leader-posing-the-biggest-threat-to-global-economy-isnt-trump-2017-05-15

Comment: "norms" are normal/normative behaviors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"norms" are normal/normative behaviors. To "trample" something is to tread all over it, as though you hadn't noticed it, or as though you did not even care that it was there. **Trample** thus means, figuratively, "to utterly disregard" or "to have no regard for".  Trump, according to the author, has no regard for the normative, conventional constraints upon a politician's behavior—upon the things he may say or do.